# How to send Longitude and latitude with class extends Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, android-broadcast

Well I am working on an app in which if i get word (Location) with any message it will send longitude latitude back with class extends broadcast receiver. Can anyone please help
Thanks in advance

```
    locationmanager = (LocationManager)     getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
    String provider = locationmanager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

    mylocation = locationmanager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);
    longitude = mylocation.getLongitude();
    latitude = mylocation.getLatitude();
```

Sending Portion

```
if(msgBody.equals("Location")){

          try {
                 SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();
                  smsManager.sendDataMessage(destinationAddress, scAddress, destinationPort, data, sentIntent, deliveryIntent)

              } catch (Exception e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
```

What to do with smsManager.sendDataMessage()?